# HDD drive freezes BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I bought new computer with x570 Aorus Master and 1TB NVMe ssd as primary boot partition.

I also bought 14TB Seagate Skyhawk AI and plugged it in system to serve as secondary drive. After adding the drive, the computer is stuck on BIOS. Motherboard displays 2A error code, and I get a Aorus Bios splash screen, without being able to enter BIOS. The HDD emits barely audible beep.

I've tried moving it to another Sata port or power rail, without success. System works if I remove the offending drive.

Is this hardware or bios issue? Should I return it, or can I get it working some other way.

Edit: Tried on another board. Sata drive isn't recognized, but at least it boots. HDD is still beeping. Put another SSD drive using same cables as HDD, and it worked.

Comment: Did you checked such a large device is supported by your motherboard controller? Also, did you seen this: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/x570-ultra-is-not-recognizing-new-wd-hc530-hdd-help.3664695/ ?

Comment: It should be. I haven't found anything to suggest it isn't. I'm probably going to try it on an older mb I own.

Comment: @DanielFath Did you follow Nikita's link through to [Power Disable Feature](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/collateral/tech-brief/tech-brief-western-digital-power-disable-pin.pdf): "If you plug a new SATA HDD with this feature into a legacy chassis or enclosure, the drive may not spin up!"?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would rather not do that. It's risky and for another HDD manufacturer.

Comment: @DanielFath It's not a WD feature, it's a [SATA spec](https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/news/hdd-sata-power-disable-feature,36146.html).

Comment: I'd rather replace it. Than risk shorts with duck tape. Plus PSU is straight power 1000w

Comment: @DanielFath Yes, be quiet! is a good PSU supplier. Did the PSU happen to come with a special SATA power adapter for "modern" HDDs?

Comment: @DanielFath There is more pertinent information at [3.3v SATA Compatibility Chart](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/a3q0d0/33v_sata_compatibility_chart_google_sheet/) if you still don't believe.

Comment: No. I believe you. But I don't want to test my rig with duct tape. I only got Sata power cord with mix of Sata and molex and pure Sata cord. I used latter, since no optical drives.